# Array in hidden input field doesn't show on post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, symfony

I want to add filenames that are uploaded to an array in a hidden input field in form. This is what I have in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myFiles[]" id="myFiles" value="">
```

This is my fileupload:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $("#submitentity").on('click', function () {
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        var filename = data.files[0]['name'];
        var type = data.files[0]['type'];

        var row = [];
        row["name"] = filename;
        row["type"] = type;
        myList[i] = row;

        i++;

        e.preventDefault();
    },
    stop: function(e){
        $("#myFiles").val(myList);
        console.log(myList);
        submitForm();
    }

});
function submitForm(){
    $('#form-Entity')[0].submit();
}
```

As you can see I have console.log(myList) what shows:

```
[Array[0], Array[0]]
  0: Array[0]
    length: 0
    name: "Hollowbody 4.gif"
    type: "image/gif"
  1: Array[0]
    length: 0
    name: "Hollowbody 5.gif"
    type: "image/gif"
```

Then I submit the form. But in my backend I get

```
array (size=1)
   0 => string '' (length=0)
```

When I want to check the myFiles...

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        $data = $form->getData();

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $data = $form->getData();

            var_dump($request->request->get('myFiles'));
            die();
```

Comment: .. And what is in your backend?

Comment: added part of my backend where I dump the myFiles

Comment: Are you actually putting an array into the hidden form field? As that won't work ... You'd be better off just doing something like a comma seperated list into it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237090/how-to-pass-array-through-hidden-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a comma seperated list as David suggested. Just did it like this:

```
myList += filename;
myList += ',';
myList += type;
myList += ',';
```