# replace input type select multiple by some kind of list to force selected elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, input

I'm trying to achieve something like on this screenshot :

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6LXf.jpg)

it's basically a form in PHP/Html, and working nicely.
however it's not exactly what I want to do.

I want to take elements from the left and put them to the right side, and get the form validated with the right side elements.

atm, everything works nicely, but my problem is : **all elements on the right side need to be "selected" before submitting the form**.

is there a way of doing this without having the elements on the right side being "selected".

technically, I just want the "pushed elements" to the right side to be all selected by default in the form.

I suppose my problem comes from the fact that I'm using select instead of another kind of input (can I use a textarea, or some kind of other input ?)

thanks

FYI, here is my source code for this

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

            function move(sens) {

                    var i, sourceSel, targetSel;

                    if (sens == 'right') {
                            sourceSel = document.getElementById('selectBoxOne');
                            targetSel = document.getElementById('selectBoxSecond');
                    } else {
                            sourceSel = document.getElementById('selectBoxSecond');
                            targetSel = document.getElementById('selectBoxOne');
                    }

                    i = sourceSel.options.length;
                    while (i--) {
                            if (sourceSel.options[i].selected) {
                                    targetSel.appendChild(sourceSel.options[i]);
                            }
                    }
            }

            </script>
```

php/html

```
<tr>
                       <th>Associated rights</th>
                       <td>
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" id="table">
                            <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            Available (unused) rights (pbroles) <br />
                                            <select name="kiki" multiple="multiple" id="selectBoxOne" size="10" style="width: 325px">
                                            <?php
                                            $q_pbroles = '
                                                    SELECT
                                                            p.name
                                                     FROM
                                                            firecall_pbroles p
                                                     WHERE
                                                            p.name not in (
                                                                            SELECT
                                                            p.name
                                                     FROM
                                                            firecall_pbroles p,
                                                            firecall_roles r,
                                                            firecall_l_roles l,
                                                            firecall_pbroles_types t
                                                     WHERE
                                                            p.id = l.pbrole_id
                                                     AND
                                                            r.id = l.role_id
                                                     AND
                                                            t.id = p.type
                                                     AND
                                                            r.id = '.$role_id.'
                                                                            )
                                                    ;';
                                            $prep = $dbh->prepare($q_pbroles);
                                            $prep->execute();
                                            $arrAll = $prep->fetchAll();
                                            foreach($arrAll as $data)
                                            {
                                                    echo '<option id="multiple'.$data['id'].'" value="'.$data['id'].'">'.$data['name'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                            <br />
                                            Ctrl+Click to select multiple pbroles
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            <input type="button" value="<<" onclick="move('left');"><br />
                                            <input type="button" value=">>" onclick="move('right');">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            pbroles in this Role<br />
                                            <select name="pbRoles[]" multiple="multiple" id="selectBoxSecond" size="10" style="width: 325px">
                                            <?php
                                            $q_pbroles = '
                                                                            SELECT
                                                                                    p.id,
                                                                                    p.name,
                                                                                    t.roletype,
                                                                                    t.descr
                                                                             FROM
                                                                                    firecall_pbroles p,
                                                                                    firecall_roles r,
                                                                                    firecall_l_roles l,
                                                                                    firecall_pbroles_types t
                                                                             WHERE
                                                                                    p.id = l.pbrole_id
                                                                             AND
                                                                                    r.id = l.role_id
                                                                             AND
                                                                                    t.id = p.type
                                                                             AND
                                                                                    r.id = '.$role_id.'
                                                                             ORDER BY
                                                                                    p.type;
                                                                            ';
                                            $prep = $dbh->prepare($q_pbroles);
                                            $prep->execute();
                                            $arrAll = $prep->fetchAll();
                                            foreach($arrAll as $data)
                                            {
                                                    echo '<option id="multiple'.$data['id'].'" value="'.$data['id'].'" selected>'.$data['name'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                            <br />
                                            Ctrl+Click to select multiple pbroles
                                    </td>


                            </tr>
                            </table>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: I did precisely this dialog control once.  In assembly, though. I have the feeling that with js, css, html, php, sql you can get a little more elegant.  Lose the table, but `select` is the right element.  Am I understanding correctly that you want all `option` in the *right* `select` when the page loads?  The one named `pbRoles[]`.

Comment: indeed :)
in fact I just want all options in the _right_ `select` to be validated in the form, regardless of their selection (I want to say "as long as the options are in the right select, they are submitted by the form" (that's the goal of a left and right select, right select is made to have the chosen options, I don't want to do two things (push them with the button + select them, even if I can select them automatically, what happens if a user deselects them by mistake ?), and not having to "select them" manually (in blue), to avoid errors if a user deselects them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

[See Paul Dixon's answer on "how to pass array through hidden field"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237117/1889685)

You can add an event listener to the form submit event and then add each `selectBoxSecond` option to a hidden field inside your form like this:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

form.onsubmit = function(e) {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden_pbRoles');
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }

    var sourceSel = document.getElementById('selectBoxSecond');
    i = sourceSel.options.length;
    while (i--) {

        var input_hidden = document.createElement("input");
        input_hidden.setAttribute('name', 'pbRoles[]');
        input_hidden.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        input_hidden.setAttribute('value', sourceSel.options[i].text);

        form.appendChild(input_hidden);
    }
};
```

Now you can also remove `name` and `multiple="multiple"` from the second `select` `selectBoxOne`:

```
<select id="selectBoxSecond" size="10" style="width: 325px">
</select>
```

You can check my working example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/listpost.php

Just move some options from the left to the right select box and then hit submit button to see the `POST` data result after the page refresh.

Comment: that's great information, thanks a lot, I will try that today and let you know if it worked, thanks for your help